# Monotouch Dialog implementation in a Class derived from UIViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, selected, monotouch.dialog

I just want to override the `Selected` method from MonoTouch.Dialog. Simple as that I can not figure out the correct way..

I have a class FirstView which derives from `UIViewController`. In it I declare

```
DialogViewController viewController = new DialogViewController();
```

Also in this class I fill the viewController with a section which contains a `UILabel`.

Now I want to act on a click on the row containing the label - I don´t want to have a button or something else with an event, I must use the override!

I know this is a fairly easy question but I just can not get it right.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to override a method in MonoTouch.Dialog then you'll need to define your own types. It's the best way to customize MonoTouch.Dialog (when events are not available).

In this case `Section` inherits from `Element` where the `Selected` methods are defined. So doing something like:

```
public class MySection : Section {
    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        // do your own processing
    }
}
```

should allow you to get your own code called/executed when `Selected` is being called.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will do it! :)